# How to update a Label in Class with QtGui

Tags: python, qt, user-interface

```
form_class = uic.loadUiType("GUI.ui")[0]  # Load the UI


class MainWindowClass(QtGui.QMainWindow, form_class):
 def __init__(self, target, Afb, np, conversion, parent=None):
    QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.startProgramm)  
    self.target = target
    self.Afb = Afb
    self.np = np
    self.conversion = conversion


 def update_Label(self):
    leistung = self.IcBox.value() * self.UceBox.value()
    self.Leistunglabel.setNum(leistung)
```

Thia a part of my class in Python. I tried also with datatime but it doesnt work.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985640/change-qlabel-text-dynamically-in-pyqt4

Comment: I dont get it, how this work

Comment: please post the relevant code and describe what exactly you want

Comment: I want to update the `Leistunglabel` every time I Change the value in `IcBox` or  `UceBox` (QSpinbox). Chust give a ecample code then i will translate it in my code

Comment: ok! :) then try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20898897/label-displays-sum-of-two-qspinbox-python-pyside